# Browser is redirecting to the IIS7 page when I try to go to www.pandora.com (I don't want it to)

Tags: browser, iis

For some reason whenever I try to go to http: //www.pandora.com I am being redirected to some basic IIS7 page. It basically consists of a simple graphic with IIS7 in the middle. Above that it says welcome, and then (I assume) it says welcome in various languages in a circle around the central IIS7 text. Somehow my IIS settings got screwed up.

Also, when I try to view the source of the image I get http: //www.pandora.com/welcome.png. So it seems like it is being rerouted to some base IIS directory or something. Seems like that should be a clue. Here is a link to the image:

[image]

The thing I don't understand is why it seems to only be doing this to Pandora, and not other webpages, my other browsing seems fine. It is also exhibiting this behavior in IE and Chrome. Any ideas on what to check or look for on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone had (I would bet a small amount) edited the %windows%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file.  (Path will vary on 64-bit systems.)  Remove the line that refers to pandora.com.

The other possibility is that you are using a corporate PC and your company doesn't want you wasting bandwidth listening to music on their dime.  If so, get the Pandora app for your cell phone--I use the BlackBerry app at work all the time and it's great.

Comment: Yeah, it was a recent change by the IT Admin. Our business is seasonal so we have a blackout through December. At least I wasn't going crazy, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running IIS7 on your machine. I would start by either diabling the world wide web service on you computer or uninstalling it. Then try to get to pandora.com and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks danbo. While I suppose that would work, removing IIS7 is not an option. I use it for work at times. Although I have not used it in a long time, which is why I am a little confused at how this happened.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are something is redirecting pandora.com to 127.0.0.1, which is your local machine. Is this a work computer? Sometimes primitive content restriction systems handle blacklisted URLs this way.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this via my IPhone 6 Plus. You can try to go to Setting & clear your History & Mobile Data. It's works for my case.

Comment: That's great but smartphones are off-topic here. Besides which you are answering a five year old question.