# Chrome redirects me to IIS7 page

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iis-7

When I use Chrome - and only when I use Chrome - I get redirected to "the IIS7" page when I try to go to some websites.

[I've seen a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/205837/browser-is-redirecting-to-the-iis7-page-when-i-try-to-go-to-www-pandora-com-i-d) asked and answered but the problem there was with the Hosts file. In my case, that isn't the problem, and strangely it only affects Chrome but not Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea on where and what the problem could be?

Comment: Could you please link to the similar questian / answer?

Comment: @IvanViktorovic done.

Comment: As the other question suggests, if you are in a corporate environment, a proxy server might block or redirect sites. Are you using such a proxy with your Chrome settings? Can you give an example of the redirected site's address? (Is the original URL being truncated or truly redirected).